# Pass comma separated string to stored procedure and apply LIKE to query for each value?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I would like to pass a comma separated string or similar (whatever is best) to a stored procedure and have it apply each value to a LIKE condition in a query.

For example if I pass @terms = "avenue,park,road" to the stored procedure it would then generate a query along the lines of:

```
SELECT *
FROM properties
WHERE
    properties.Address LIKE @terms[0] OR
    properties.Address LIKE @terms[1] OR
    properties.Address LIKE @terms[2]
```

It needs to work with SQL server 2008. Can anyone advise me of the best approach? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns   take a look at that.. you can use something similar to split them out and then do your LIKE

Comment: i would do something like this using the xml data type.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/46596

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function that splits a string and returns it as a table.
You can then join onto it like a normal table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_SPLIT_TBL](@InExp varchar(8000), @Sep varchar(10)) 
RETURNS @Res    TABLE(
    Pos         int,
    Value       varchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
    WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
        SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@Sep, @InExp)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @InExp, stop + 1)
        FROM Pieces
        WHERE stop > 0
    )

    INSERT INTO @Res
    SELECT pn, SUBSTRING(@InExp, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS s
    FROM Pieces OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);

    RETURN;
END
```

Usage

```
SELECT b.Field 
FROM DBO.[FN_SPLIT_TBL]('TEST1,TEST2', ',') a
    JOIN YOURTABLE b ON b.Field LIKE a.Value + '%'
```

Returns

```
Pos Value
----------
1   TEST1
2   TEST2
```

That should do the trick